# How can I create an image placeholder of an image I am fetching from the web?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am given the image size, and i want to create a placeholder of that image size's ratio. A simple solid gray color is fine.

Comment: `imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(50,50,50));` might work

Comment: make a custom `Drawable` class and override its intrinsic size to match original image ratio, you can also use a `ShapeDrawable` class, its up to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create one in code like this:

```java
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.GRAY);
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, p);
```

but I think it's easier to just create an XML drawable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFCCCCCC"/>
</shape>
```

You can set that on the `ImageView` using its `R.drawable` ID, and then you don't have to worry about your memory use because Android is handling caching and all that.

Comment: how would i use the drawable and resize it accordingly?

Comment: If you set it on an ImageView, it'll automatically fill the entire thing. If that's not an option, load it manually using `getResources().getDrawable(int)`, cast it to `ShapeDrawable`, call `mutate()`, and then call `setIntrinsicWidth()` and `setIntrinsicHeight()`.

Comment: <shape> tag leads to `GradientDrawable`, not `ShapeDrawable` (yes: its strange but its true), so use `setSize(int, int)`

Comment: @pskink now that you mention it, I think I've seen that. Bleh.

Comment: last question (i think). so lets say that the size i get is like 3200 x 1800. Would i have to do some math to calculate the ratio? or will android take care of resizing properly? basically i don't want to hit out of memory

Comment: @Sree if you want to use solid color it doesn't matter if you use 3200 x 1800 or 32 x 18 or 16 x 9

Comment: That's certainly large enough that you'll want to be careful. @pskink's custom Drawable suggestion is very good, it's a simple base class to implement and you're guaranteed not to have to allocate your own Bitmap or Canvas. The `GradientDrawable` thing threw me off with the XML resource idea; you can't set intrinsic size on those.

Comment: @Barend actualy you can also use `ShapeDrawable` and `GradientDrawable`: they also dont use any `Bitmaps` but are limited in use, with custom `Drawable` class you can draw whatever you want

Comment: @Barend you **can** set intrinsic size of GradientDrawable: setSize(int, int), see the sources

Comment: @pskink you're right again. Android's API is so wonderfully consistent. Can you tell I'm not writing code in the background while answering this? :P

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bitmap using this method [createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)) and set it to ImageView using [setImageBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap))